# Secure App to API communication

Tags: android, api, security, communication

I have developed an Android app and a node.js API on my Server. I want to ensure that only API commands from the APP are accepted by the Server and that no hacker can Spam my Server. If I would use a password I would have to save it in the app and I think it's not very hard to open an apk file and find the password. 
I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Lukas